# UItableview methods not being called in a XIB

Tags: uitableview, delegates, swift4, xib

I am trying to use a three tableviews in a XIB. I've created a custom UITableViewCell class, however when I am trying to use it, comes up with an error saying..."Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I have tried regist

```
 internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{


    if tableView == resultsTable {
    if savedWheelsArray.count > 0 {
        self.resultsTable.register(accessoryCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "accessoryCell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "accessoryCell" , for: indexPath) as! accessoryCellTableViewCell

        //let wheel = savedWheelsArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.AccessoryTitle.text = "WTF"
        cell.AcessoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "history")

    print("set up searched wheels cell")
    return cell
    }
        else {
            let cellIdentifier : String = "accessoryCell"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! accessoryCellTableViewCell

            cell.AccessoryTitle.text = "no saved wheels"
            cell.AcessoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "history")
       print("no saved wheels found")
        return cell
    }
    }
    else {

    }
    return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Comment: Put this line in viewdidload.  self.resultsTable.register(accessoryCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "accessoryCell")

Comment: I've tried that...still the same :/

Comment: Could you please share your crash logs and at which line it is crashing?

Comment: you need to register cell with identifier "accessoryCell" for both of your tables in the 'viewDidLoad' method

Comment: i just get '(lldb) '

Comment: and then hread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value next to the first property of the cell